# Is there a way to send panda dataframe to an existing excel sheet using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add a dataframe and an image to an excel sheet. I can do it one order but not in the other. First adding the dataframe and then adding the image works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('/home/ahmed/Okay.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

R=np.random.randint(0,10,[10,8])
D=pd.DataFrame(data=R)
D.to_excel(writer,'my_new_sheet',startrow=0)

sheet1=writer.sheets['my_new_sheet']
sheet1.insert_image('A15', '/home/ahmed/dna1.jpg', {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})
writer.save()
```

But the opposite doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('/home/ahmed/Okay.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
book=writer.book
sheet1=book.add_worksheet('my_new_sheet')
sheet1.insert_image('A15', '/home/ahmed/dna1.jpg', {'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})


R=np.random.randint(0,10,[10,8])
D=pd.DataFrame(data=R)
D.to_excel(writer,'my_new_sheet',startrow=0)
writer.save()
```

It appears `.to_excel()` method creates new sheet with provided name and throws exception when it matches with existing sheets. Is there any way to send dataframe to existing sheets (with or without using `.to_excel()` method)?